# sum multiple lines in csv when fields match within file

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a file that I've trimmed down to look like the following:

```
"Reno","40.00"
"Reno","40.00"
"Reno","80.00"
"Reno","60.00"
"Lakewood","150.00"
"Altamonte Springs","50.25"
"Altamonte Springs","25.00"
"Altamonte Springs","25.00"
"Sandpoint","50.00"
"Lenoir City","987.00"
```

etc.

What I want to end up with is a sum of the total amount per city. That is:

```
"Reno","220.00"
"Lakewood","150.00"
"Altamonte Springs","100.25"
```

Etc.

Fair warning, the data set is not necessarily continuous-that is, a city may appear once here, once a thousand lines down, and 3 more times at the end.

I've been trying to use the following awk script:

```
awk -F "," '{array[$1]+=$2} END { for (i in array) {print i"," array[i]}}' test1.csv > test6.csv
```

The results I'm getting look like this:

```
"Matawan",0
"Bay Side",0
"Pataskala",0
"Dorothy",0
"Haymarket",0
"Myrtle Point",0
```

Etc. All zeros on the second column, and no quotes.

I'm obviously missing something, but I don't know what or where else to look. What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you failed is because of the double quotes.

Do something like this:

```
sed 's/"//g' file.csv | awk -F "," '{array[$1]+=$2}END{for(i in array) {print "\""  i "\""  ","  "\"" array[i] "\"" }}' 

"Lenoir City","987"
"Reno","220"
"Lakewood","150"
"Sandpoint","50"
"Altamonte Springs","100.25"
```

Comment: This strips the quotes completely. The OP wants the quotes in output.

Comment: well, I can get rid of the last `sed` if you want and only use `awk`

Comment: Getting rid of the last `sed` != only using `awk`.

Comment: `sed 's/"//g'` => `tr -d \"`

Comment: @twalberg, thanks, that's better way to do it. In theory I could use `awk` only but it requires more typing.

Answer (score 2):

This awk one-liner would give exactly what you want with formatting :

```
awk -F'","' '{a[$1]+=$2*1}END{for (x in a)printf "%s\",\"%.2f\"\n", x,a[x]}' file
```

test with your data:

```
kent$  cat f
"Reno","40.00"
"Reno","40.00"
"Reno","80.00"
"Reno","60.00"
"Lakewood","150.00"
"Altamonte Springs","50.25"
"Altamonte Springs","25.00"
"Altamonte Springs","25.00"
"Sandpoint","50.00"
"Lenoir City","987.00"

kent$  awk -F'","' '{a[$1]+=$2*1}END{for (x in a)printf "%s\",\"%.2f\"\n", x,a[x]}' f
"Lakewood","150.00"
"Reno","220.00"
"Lenoir City","987.00"
"Sandpoint","50.00"
"Altamonte Springs","100.25"
```

Answer (score 1):

`"` is causing problem in your input. First remove them using `sed` and print it back using `printf` inside `awk`

Try following:

```
sed 's/"//g' input.csv | awk -F "," '{array[$1]+=$2} END { for (i in array) {printf "\"%s\",\"%\"\n", i, array[i]}}' > output.csv
```

**Jumbled Input**

```
"Reno","40.00"
"Reno","60.00"
"Lakewood","150.00"
"Altamonte Springs","50.25"
"Altamonte Springs","25.00"
"Reno","80.00"
"Sandpoint","50.00"
"Reno","40.00"
"Lenoir City","987.00"
"Altamonte Springs","25.00"
```

**Output**

```
"Reno","220.00"
"Altamonte Springs","100.25"
"Lakewood","150.00"
"Lenoir City","987.00"
"Sandpoint","50.00"
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need pre-processing or nasty escaping:

```
$ awk -F'"' '{a[$2]+=$4}END{for(k in a)printf "%s,%s\n",FS k FS,FS a[k] FS}' file
"Lenoir City","987"
"Reno","220"
"Lakewood","150"
"Sandpoint","50"
"Altamonte Springs","100.25"
```